# Set threshold and back-out queue programatically for IBM MQ

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms, pcf

Is there a way to set the back-out threshold and back-out queue in Java? I don't have access to MQ Console to manually set these as I am using Testcontainers. So each test run should set these property on the queue. Currently I am using JMS to send messages to the queue, and I want to set a threshold to 3 so as soon as the threshold reaches I will transfer the message to the back-out queue. Currently the message redelivers indefinitely.

I tried using MQ as shown in [this article](https://www.capitalware.com/rl_blog/?p=2954). However, it just sends a message to the queue.

After reading the comments I tried doing through PCF

```
PCFMessageAgent agent = new PCFMessageAgent(queueManager);
PCFMessage request = new PCFMessage(MQConstants.MQCMD_CHANGE_Q);
request.addParameter(MQConstants.MQCA_Q_NAME, queueName);
request.addParameter(MQConstants.MQIA_BACKOUT_THRESHOLD, 3);
request.addParameter(MQConstants.MQCA_BACKOUT_REQ_Q_NAME, backoutQueue);
agent.send(request);
```

It just throws PCFException `MQJE001: Completion Code 2, Reason 3014.`

Comment: That blog is for sending to a z/OS (Mainframe) queue manager.   I'm sure Roger had other examples that works be a better fit for you.   As part of the container I think you can also add commands you want executed when the queue manager is created, this could be used to create the BOQ and set the values you want on the main app queue.

Comment: You might be better to copy this one - https://www.capitalware.com/rl_blog/?p=6988, but change the command from MQCMD_CREATE_Q to MQCMD_CHANGE_Q and then set up the parameters you need.

Comment: You need the queue type as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Morag for pointing me to right direction. For anyone who wants to setup.

```
   PCFMessageAgent agent = new PCFMessageAgent(queueManager);
   PCFMessage request = new PCFMessage(MQConstants.MQCMD_CHANGE_Q);
   request.addParameter(MQConstants.MQCA_Q_NAME, queueName);
   request.addParameter(MQConstants.MQIA_Q_TYPE, MQConstants.MQQT_LOCAL);
   request.addParameter(MQConstants.MQIA_BACKOUT_THRESHOLD, 3);
   request.addParameter(MQConstants.MQCA_BACKOUT_REQ_Q_NAME, backoutQueue);
   agent.send(request);
```